# How to find the number of elements of a two-dimensional array, read from a file?

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I have a file. Inside the file I have stored a two-dimensional array, something like this:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Lengths of arrays can vary and they are not always 10 elements long.

I read the array from the file using this method:

```
map = IO.readlines("test.txt")
```

and when i print the result using:

```
map.each {|x| puts "#{x}"}
```

the output is what I expect it to be. But if I try to get the row length using:

```
puts map[0].length
```

I get 320 instead of 10 (which is what I expect).

Can someone explain me why am I getting `320` instead of `10` ?

Comment: Can you attach the file you have problem with?

Comment: File is a TXT with the first case 10x10 I reported.

Comment: IO.readlines returns array of strings. 320 is length of string which represents array of array in ruby language. To get 10 you need to parse the file (actually only 1 line) and instantiate ruby arrays to ask them about their length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `IO#readlines` you should use [`JSON#parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) since it’s a valid json:

```
require 'json'    
JSON.parse(File.read("test.txt"))
#⇒ [[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
#   [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
#   [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
#   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: It's work! I read more about JSON and know I understand the power of parsing! Thank you both!